# Does a recent general review of recurrent neural networks exist?

Tags: reference-request, theoretical-neuroscience, neural-network

Does anyone know of a comparatively recent paper reviewing the literature on psychological applications of recurrent neural networks?
I'm looking for a paper which provides a general overview of the use of this class of models (Elman networks, Hopfield networks, Boltzmann machines, localist attractor networks, etc.) in modelling psychological processes.

More practically, I have a line in a draft paper which currently says "A full discussion of this class of models is beyond the scope of the current review (see XXXX), but [...]" and I want to fill in the Xs.

I have Rogers and McClelland's (2004) Semantic Cognition, which is a nice review, but focuses on feed-forward models. Suggestions?

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question as written. There are many types of recurrent neural networks that have been applied to even more areas of psychology. Could you either narrow it down to a smaller subset of recurrent neural networks, or define what areas of psychology you might be interested in here? (I realize you may not be more interested in any one area than in any other here, but it simply seems too broad.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the broad answer is the one I'm looking for - I have plenty of papers on applications of these models to specific problem domains, but I'm looking for something I can point to as a more general introduction. I'm looking through *Behavioural Brain Research* right now, as they do publish papers with this kind of broad scope.

Comment: More practically, I have a line in a draft paper which currently says "A full discussion of this class of models is beyond the scope of the current review (see **XXXX**), but [...] " and I want to fill in the Xs.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a bit already. I'll take your word that the question probably has an answer that fits the SE format, but adding more information about what motivates the question (such as the above) and suggested starting points would be **very** helpful.

Comment: Also, in the comment above, I meant *Annual Review of Psychology*, although I'll be checking BBR too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be a single paper that reviews all models, but I have listed some articles and books below that may meet your needs.

Asakawa, Shinichi. (2003). Psychological applicability of simple recurrent neural networks. *Japanese Psychological Review, 46*(2), 274-287.

De Mulder, W., Bethard, S., & Moens, M. F. (2015). A survey on the application of recurrent neural networks to statistical language modeling. *Computer Speech & Language, 30*(1), 61-98.

Jacobsson, H. (2005). Rule extraction from recurrent neural networks: A taxonomy and review. *Neural Computation, 17*(6), 1223-1263.

Rojas, R. (2013). *Neural networks: a systematic introduction.* Springer Science & Business Media.

Subathra, B., & Radhakrishnan, T. K. (2012). Recurrent neuro fuzzy and fuzzy neural hybrid networks: a review. *Instrumentation Science & Technology, 40*(1), 29-50.

Suykens, J. A., Vandewalle, J. P., & de Moor, B. L. (2012). *Artificial neural networks for modelling and control of non-linear systems.* Springer Science & Business Media.

Zhang, H., Wang, Z., & Liu, D. (2014). A comprehensive review of stability analysis of continuous-time recurrent neural networks. *Neural Networks and Learning Systems, IEEE Transactions on, 25*(7), 1229-1262.